# multi section UITableView and NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an NSArray with 5 objects.

```
NSArray *tmpArry2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test1", @"test2", @"test3", @"test4", @"test5",nil];
```

I have a table with 4 sections (see screenshot)

What I want to do is show

- test1 in 1st section
- test2 and test3 in 2nd sections
- test4 in 3rd section
- test5 in 4th section

Here's the problem that I have the index.row and index.section for each of them goes from

```
indexPath.row: 0 ... indexPath.section: 0
indexPath.row: 0 ... indexPath.section: 1
indexPath.row: 1 ... indexPath.section: 1
indexPath.row: 0 ... indexPath.section: 2
indexPath.row: 0 ... indexPath.section: 3
```

I was hoping to use the indexPath.section to get to value in tmpArry2 but I am not sure how I can do that. I thought about creating a global static int counter = 0; and keep incrementing it in cellForRowAtIndexPath but the problem is that if I scroll up and down the values keep jumping between cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // Use the default cell style.
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d ... indexPath.section: %d ...", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);

//this will not give me right results
//NSString *titleStr2 = [tmpArry2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should help, but I did not understand why do you have titles in tmpArry2 and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method countDownArray? I assume you rename it in somewhere in your code.

if you place the following code in you cellForRowAtIndexPath method, it should work.

```
NSInteger index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    index += [self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
index += indexPath.row;
cell.textLabel.text = [countDownArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: sorry - i had a typo. I usually dumb down my question when i post it here. I missed a few variables

Comment: Thank you for the brilliantly simple answer! works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the structure of tmpArry2 to have sub arrays -- that's one usual way to do sections. So the array should look like this (using the new notation for arrays):

```
NSArray *tmpArry2 = @[@[@"test1"], @[@"test2", @"test3"], @[@"test4"], @[@"test5"]];
```

This gives you an array with 4 objects, each of which is an array. Then in your data source methods you would do this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return tmpArry2.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tmpArry2[section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = tmpArry2[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```